# Getting Failed to load resource: net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME error in my HTML5 application

Tags: android, jquery, html, trigger.io

I am working on HTML5 application with Trigger IO framework.I tested it on iPhone and it is working well there.But problem is with the Android. I am getting following error when I debug the application.

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
```

this is for every resource file referenced from the html header. My header code is :

```
 <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/index.js"></script>
```

both files are present on the location and working well on iOS. But problem is with Android/Chrome. Any workaround ?

**EDIT**

Following is the header of the index.html :

```
      <head>
        <title>My App</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
'self'; img-src https://*; child-src 'none';">    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slick.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/slick-theme.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/network.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/slick.min.js"></script>
     </head>
```

Note : If I remove jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js file then it is taking reference of index.js

Comment: This MAYBE a problem with Content Security Policy (CSP).This entry in your HTML will turn off ALL security:- <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">  Give it a try, this will isolate the problem. NOTE this line is NOT to be used in production, it leaves you open to security vulnerabilities.

Comment: @JonGoodwin: No ,unfortunately this did not help. One more thing to note is , if I remove jquery_mobile_min.js then it is working

Comment: @KalaBalik : Nothing fancy in the HTML . Its a regulation code . Still I am editing question with header part.

Comment: @KalaBalik : It is already inside my document. My iOS app is working fine. But problem is only with Android.

Comment: There is a typo in your <head> :- 'self'; img-src https://*; child-src 'none';"> Please show your logcat and do some console logging. I saw a comment earlier that suggested making a HUGE index.html by pasting the javascript directly into it, worth a try to isolate the problem.

Comment: I deleted my answer as it contained some missleading info. Still i believe your problem is in with jquery mobile trying to add some custom protocols like  ` href="tel://.." ` . Similar issue was being discussed here https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme/issues/156

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be a regression of:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/6746

You can use the `httpd` module as a workaround for this and similar bugs in other libraries:

https://trigger.io/modules/httpd/current/docs/index.html

Comment: @Antonie : Super (y) . I was expecting this bullseye from you :)